# Macroable.php Method foregin does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need help in solving this issue

In Macroable.php line 99:
  Method foregin does not exist.

image link 1: https://prnt.sc/n2z0gl
image link 2: https://prnt.sc/n2z0mu

used this :

```
namespace Illuminate\Support\Traits;

use Closure;
use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionMethod;
use BadMethodCallException;
```

Line of coding :

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$method} does not exist.");
        }

        $macro = static::$macros[$method];

        if ($macro instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func_array($macro->bindTo($this, static::class), $parameters);
        }

        return call_user_func_array($macro, $parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: please share you migration code also..

Comment: this has been fixed. Now another error on this
Array to string conversion

Img link : https://prnt.sc/n31o65

Comment: pls see the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **.** (dot) by **,** (comma)

```
return view('companies.index', ['companies' => $companies]);
```